# switch vs if-else branching control structure in Node.JS

Tags: node.js

Which one is good to use when there is a large number of branching flow in Node.JS Program.

switch

```
switch(n)
{
case 1:
  execute code block 1
  break;
case 2:
  execute code block 2
  break;
default:
  code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
}
```

OR
if-else

```
if (condition1)
  {
    execute code block 1
  }
else if(condition2)
  {
    execute code block 2
  } 
else
  {
     code to be executed if n is different from condition1 and condition2
  }
```

Comment: `switch` seems preferable if the conditions consist of checking `n` for a specific value.

Comment: @karaxuna: It matters with the languages i.e. c++ you pointed to `Its a compiled language` and I asked in `Node.JS - interpreted language`. So please consider undoing your close vote..

Comment: @karaxuna If you read the question you pointed to. Answer says `Use switch.  In the worst case the compiler will generate the same code as a if-else chain,` i.e. compiler will generate the same code.. But Node.JS is interpreted language

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For just a few items, the difference is small. If you have many items you should definitely use a switch. It give  better performance than if-else.

If a switch contains more than five items, it's implemented using a lookup table or a hash list. This means that all items get the same access time, compared to a list of if-else  where the last item takes much more time to reach as it has to evaluate every previous condition first..

Comment: While the `switch` statement probably is faster (and the meaning more obvious) I think the assertion about the last condition being slowest is wrong. This is a typical case where branch prediction would kick in so that the most common option would be fastest.

Answer (score 7):

```
switch(n)
{
case 1,3,4:
     execute code block 1
     break;
case 2,5,9,10:
     execute code block 2
     break;
default:
      code to be executed if n is different from first 2 cases.
}
```

To write down the if...else if...else steps for the above case, you will have to write the 'OR (||)' condition-statement and repeat the variable 'n' in the statement, Where as switch cases can be separated by just a comma ','. Thus switch is more readable for such a case.